# How to list purchased items from android market

Tags: android, google-play

I'm creating an application with In App billing and was wondering if it's possible to retrieve the purchased items list from the android market.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing what you're looking for is `RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS`. Read this [information](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_admin.html#billing-purchase-type) for details.